# How can I deallocate my view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a login screen that I allocate in one place, and dismiss in another, and upon dismissal, its `dealloc` method is never called and the iVar holding the login screen still has a value even after being assigned nil in my dismissal code.

**Here is my allocation**

```
-(void)loginUser
    {
        loginScreen = [[LoginScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginScreen" bundle:nil];

        [self.tabBarController addChildViewController:loginScreen];
        [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:loginScreen.view];
        [loginScreen didMoveToParentViewController:self.tabBarController];
        [self.tabBarController.view bringSubviewToFront:loginScreen.view];
    }
```

**Here is my dismissal and deallocation in another method (which fails to deallocate)**

```
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
             loginScreen.view.frame = CGRectOffset(frame, -1024, 0);
         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             // Remove the loginScreen
                             [loginScreen willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
                             [loginScreen.view removeFromSuperview];
                             [loginScreen removeFromParentViewController];
                             [loginScreen cleanupBeforeDealloc];
                             loginScreen = nil;
                         }];
```

I have some code that listens for keyboard notifications inside LoginScreen, but I added a method below to clean that up, and I tried calling it in my dismissal code above, but that still didn't fix it.  grrrr.

```
-(void)cleanupBeforeDealloc
    {
        [self deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    }
```

Comment: You have something keeping a strong reference to itself inside your loginScreen. Add your loginScreen code if you want us to find out what it is. You don't deallocate your viewControllers manually, ARC handles that for you.

Comment: @Sneak.  No, i'm sorry, I don't have anything keeping a strong reference.  I've searched my entire project using the regular expression 'loginscreen' and every instance/usage in code is accounted for in the two methods above.  I was going to post a screenshot, but stackoverflow/imagur is failing to accept picture uploads at the moment.

Comment: Right. If `dealloc` is not called when it should be, you have a retain cycle. You can use the Leaks instrument to track it down.

Comment: @matt  How can I find this retain... literally ALL of the code for my login screen alloc/dealloc is shown above per a project wide regular expression search for LoginScreen.  I've used Instruments/Allocations, and it shows me the allocation of course, but doesn't show me any deallocation.  I have breakpointed the dismissal code above, but still nothing

Comment: Ah yes, retain cycles are hell. Anybody could be holding a strong reference to your view controller -- check for strong properties, look for outstanding closures (i.e. for timers or callbacks which refer to self), also unsubscribe from NSNotifications... what else, did I miss anything?

Comment: @joeybladb.  I do subscribe to keyboard notifications in the LoginScreen.  I was attempting to unsubscribe in my LoginScreen dealloc, but dealloc is never called.

Comment: That's the problem right there. You cannot unsubscribe from a notification in `dealloc`. The notification is causing the extra retain and thus `dealloc` is never called.

Comment: @matt   Checking now to see if that solves it.

Comment: What you need to look for is `self` references _inside_ `loginScreen`, not `loginScreen` references.

Comment: @matt.  It was the notifications.  If you change your answer I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest getting rid of `loginScreen` entirely. There is no need for it, as this is a child view controller and is accessible through your `childViewControllers` array. `childViewControllers` manages the retain and release for the child view controller, and your `loginScreen` property is adding an extra retain that could be messing things up.

However, the actual *cause* of the retain cycle is probably that the view controller has registered and retained an observer with the notification center. That is a common cause of retain cycles. The notification center retains the observer and the observer retains `self`. You cannot unregister in `dealloc` to break the cycle because the retain means that `dealloc` isn't called.

Comment: For further discussion, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_unusual_memory_management_situations As I point out there, NSTimer is another common case.